# Get list of variable type by group

Tags: r

I know how to get a list of variables types with:

```
unlist(lapply(dat, class))
```

but is there a way to either have returned only variables of one class (eg factors) or have the full list grouped by class? I'd like to be able to quickly identify all variables that are numeric, factors, etc. For the sake of an example:

```
mtcars$vs <- factor(mtcars$vs)
mtcars$am <- factor(mtcars$am)
mtcars$gear <- factor(mtcars$gear)
mtcars$carb <- factor(mtcars$carb)

unlist(lapply(mtcars, class))
  mpg       cyl      disp        hp      drat        wt      qsec        vs        am      gear      carb 
"numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric"  "factor"  "factor"  "factor"  "factor"
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with expected output.

Comment: `x = unlist(lapply(mtcars, class)); x[x == "factor"]`? The desired output still is not clear... maybe `split(names(x), x)`? Btw, you might want to look at `?sapply`.

Comment: You can use `is.factor`, `is.numeric` etc to identify which columns are factor, numeric etc. Also, instead of using `unlist(lapply(...,`, use `sapply`, `sapply(data, is.factor)` and then subset those columns which are `TRUE`.

Comment: you could just `sort` the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select columns based on their structure using `dplyr::select_if()`.

```
require(tidyverse)

diamonds %>% 
  select_if(is.factor)

# A tibble: 53,940 x 3
   cut       color clarity
   <ord>     <ord> <ord>  
 1 Ideal     E     SI2    
 2 Premium   E     SI1    
 3 Good      E     VS1    
 4 Premium   I     VS2    
 5 Good      J     SI2    
 6 Very Good J     VVS2   
 7 Very Good I     VVS1   
 8 Very Good H     SI1    
 9 Fair      E     VS2    
10 Very Good H     VS1    
# ... with 53,930 more rows
```